# Need Help Implementing Flagging Feature iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I haven't been able to find the answer on stackoverflow.com or on google.com I need help on figuring out how to add a flagging feature for user generated content such as if there is an inappropriate image a user can flag it so I the admin can handle this.

I currently use Parse as my back end, and couldn't find anything in their documentation for implementing such a feature.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all a flag is is just another field right?

So the most common method to do this is to add an extra field/column to the Parse object you want to allow users to flag.

One way to do this is to add a flat boolean where a user "flagging" it sets it to true or just leaves it as such.

Another way if you want to prioritize flags would be to add a "number of flags" field where each time a user flags it, the number is incremented by one. Then you can sort the objects by that number in your dashboard and act accordingly on the most often flagged items. If you want to do it this way, you may also want to prevent users from flagging the same thing multiple times. You can do this by either adding a "flagged users" array to the object where you add the user to the array before you increment the count and check to make sure it's not already in there before doing so.

Comment: haha I don't know why I'm trying to make it more complicated than need be. Thank you for your help!